# How to convert html to doc/docx with OpenOffice or LibreOffice?

Tags: linux, openoffice, libreoffice

I am trying to convert a html to doc or docx. I used some of the available php classes but the results are not good. I wonder if I can convert a html file to doc using some office software like LibreOffice or OpenOffice?

LibreOffice (AbiWord) "converts" html to a doc file but without formatting. I mean I see the html sourcecode when I open the doc file.

```
abiword --plugin AbiCommand
convert /home/qqq/test/test.htm /home/qqq/test/test.doc doc
```

And with openOffice, nothing happens..:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to doc:DOC  /home/qqq/test/test.htm
```

I have to press ctrl+c to get back to the console.

Any Ideas how to convert html to doc? I can open the html in the desktop version of these two apps and save as doc but it seems not to work in the console version.

Comment: IIRC, libre/openoffice won't work unless there's only one instance of it open. That might be your problem with the second command.

Comment: `pandoc` does this quite well, but you specifically limited your question to OO / LO so I'm not putting this an an answer...

Comment: @Jan - installed and tested. It does not work. It renames the html to docx but without actually converting it. :( I am open for any solution.

Comment: Just re-checked, works as supposed to: `pandoc -s -r html page.html -o output.docx`... It's a _very_ complex program and you have to get used tto it though.

Comment: if you open the output.docx in a text editor you will see that it is just the html sourcecode. And the sourcecode is also broken by pandoc. The html in the docx is not the same as my source html - the result looks terrible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very late response, but I hope it helps a few people.

**LibreOffice makes use of filters**

In the below code example (converting HTML to PDF, for example), you'll notice secondary optional arguments, such as --infilter=writerglobal8_HTML and :writer_web_pdf_Export:

```
soffice --headless --infilter=writerglobal8_HTML  --convert-to pdf:writer_web_pdf_Export --outdir /SomeFolder/Output /SomeFolder/Example.html
```

These are known as 'filters'. It's equivalent to the subcategories of individual filetypes. For example, a .doc could be a Microsoft Office 95 document, or a 2003 Document. It basically gives LibreOffice a clue as to what format the file is in.

There's two types of filter, an in filter (which is basically 'what sub-format is the incoming file') and an out filter (what format is the outgoing, IE exported, file in).

In your case, valid DOC filters include (where spaces are included, you'd likely need to use quotations, but I often find quotes don't work, so your mileage may vary):

```
MS WinWord 5
MS WinWord 6.0
MS Word 2003 XML      
MS Word 2007 XML      
MS Word 2007 XML Template      
MS Word 2007 XML VBA      
MS Word 95      
MS Word 95 Vorlage      
MS Word 97      
MS Word 97 Vorlage      
MS_Works      
MS_Write
```

You can work out some of the file filters from the (somewhat disorganised) .ODS sheet LibreOffice supplies found [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/upfiles/14478061067325683.ods).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it.

Open file as html in LibreOffice Writer.

File -> Export ... as ODT.

Open the ODT file with LibreOffice Writer.

Save it as a Docx file.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dumb solution, or idiocratic to a few particulars of the HTML files I'm using, but try renaming the file with a *.docx* extension. I've been able to open them as "word" files and subsequently *save* them as word files.

Comment: Well, if it works it works.